# Are C++ template functions safe to use in signal handlers?

Tags: c++

Suppose I define a global function that looks like this:

```
template <typename Class> void foo(Class& bar) { /* ... */ }
```

Where I pass for `bar` a global variable of type `Class`.

This function only calls methods that modify the contents of `bar` object, and causes no other side-effects.

Can I safely call a template function like this from a signal handler, without causing undefined behavior? Assume that no other threads are modifying or accessing this particular class instance.

Comment: That's a **template**; it's a pattern for creating functions. If the function will work properly as a signal handler, it doesn't matter whether it was written as an ordinary function or it was generated from a template. In short: `template` is irrelevant. What matters is what's inside the `/* ... */`.

Comment: *"Assume that no other threads are modifying or accessing this particular class instance"* - what about the temporarily stopped main thread? Anyway, using templates is not a problem per se, it depends on what exactly do you do with the class in the signal handler.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I read in the POSIX standard somewhere that the thread (in the case of a single-threaded program it's the main thread) that runs the signal handler temporarily stops running the code that was running when the signal came.

Comment: @Zenul_Abidin yes, sure, what I am saying though is that if the main thread is in the middle of using the class and you get a signal, your signal handler runs and operates on an inconsistent state of the class. Make sure this can't happen, use async-signal-safe functions, and you should be safe.